# How futex works in this case?

Tags: c, linux, mutual-exclusion, futex

I have a sample code of futex.
But i couldnt understand the code flow....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <linux/futex.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM 50

int futex_addr;

int futex_wait(void* addr, int val1){
  return syscall(SYS_futex,&futex_addr,val1, NULL, NULL, 0);
}
int futex_wake(void* addr, int n){
  return syscall(SYS_futex, addr, FUTEX_WAKE, n, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

void* thread_f(void* par){
        int id = (int) par;

    /*go to sleep*/
    futex_addr = 0;
    futex_wait(&futex_addr,0);

        printf("Thread %d starting to work!\n",id);
        return NULL;
}

int main(){
        pthread_t threads[NUM];
        int i;

        for (i=0;i<NUM;i++){
                pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,thread_f,(void *)i);
        }

        printf("Everyone wait...\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("Now go!\n");
    /*wake threads*/
    futex_wake(&futex_addr,50);

    /*give the threads time to complete their tasks*/
        sleep(1);


    printf("Main is quitting...\n");
        return 0;
}
```

the output comes like this :

```
Everyone wait...
Now go!
Thread 0 starting to work!
Thread 1 starting to work!
Thread 2 starting to work!
Thread 3 starting to work!
Thread 4 starting to work!
Thread 5 starting to work!
Thread 6 starting to work!
Thread 7 starting to work
Thread 8 starting to work!
Thread 9 starting to work!
.
.
Main is quitting
```

How does actually this code is behaving??

what is the trigger for thread_f functions??

How does wait & wake working here??

Comment: Don't use futex; use pthreads (which is built above futexes)

Comment: yeah.. but this is just a sample code i got... but i want to understand how the code is executing....!!

Comment: Then read [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) and understand that it is only for developers of thread libraries (e.g. developers of gnu libc + pthreads)

Answer (score 4):

1. You create 50 threads and put the main thread to sleep.
2. Within each thread, you set the value of `futex_addr` to zero (redundantly).
3. You call `futex_wait` with the address of that value, and a value parameter of zero. That means *"block, if the value I point to is (still) really zero"*.
4. `sys_futex` checks that the value at `&futex_addr` is really zero, which is the condition for blocking your thread (that is important for the correct operability of the syscall, otherwise `futex_wake` would have to block alike `NtReleaseKeyedEvent` under Windows). Of course the value is zero, that's all any thread has ever written to it, so your thread blocks.
5. The main thread eventually returns from `sleep` and calls `futex_wake` with a parameter of 50, which means *"wake (up to) 50 threads that are waiting on `&futex_addr`"*. So all your 50 threads wake up in one big thundering herd.
6. Each thread writes a message to `stdout` (without synchronization, so you might see garbled output) and exits.
7. The main thread exits as well, without joining threads or synchronizing, but due to the second call to `sleep`, chances are that it will "work fine" without evil things happening, anyway (not that it's a good thing to write code like this!).

Note that this method of waking `N` threads *works*, but is discouraged (much like using `futex` in the first place is discouraged, too). Typically you want to wake exactly one thread (use `1`), or all threads (use `INT_MAX`).

Comment: I mean to say first "Everyone wait..." gets printed later "Thread %d starting to work!\n" gets printed. Surprisingly thread_f call is before "Everyone wait..." print....

Comment: The trigger for `thread_f` is `pthread_create`, which is subject to a) the main thread being scheduled b) a dozen launching threads competing with the main thread for CPU time c) "random stuff" and d) non-synchronized use of stdio functions, which can give unpredictable output. It is not specified which thread is scheduled first after `clone` (which is what happens inside `pthread_create`). Most likely they'll start in the order the main thread created them, but something different _could_ happen. Similar is true for `printf` and `write` (which is internally called). They're not atomic.

Comment: So, the output that you see is not very well-defined. You could see thread 4 output "Everyone wait" before thread 1 outputs "Starting", and you could even _see_ the output of thread 6 first, even though thread 1 is scheduled first (and interrupted again for some reason). Or, you could see half-complete messages, or complete garbage, even that is possible.